# Oracle ATG 10 BCC promotion

Tags: atg

I am trying to figure out which promotion has been applied on few orders in ATG 10.

How can I find where to check and what to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the orders that are placed, look at the amountInfo object at the order and and under that the priceAdjustments. The priceAdjustments contain every step of the adjustment for arriving at the price and if a promotion is involved, you'll see it in the adjustments. Similarly, you'll find a priceInfo object on each CommerceItem under order with adjustments.

For more details, please refer to the following:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E41069_01/Platform.11-0/ATGCommProgGuide/html/s1003itempricecalculator01.html

- Jags

Answer (score 0):

On the orders that are placed look at the priceInfo object hat has got adjustments which will give you the promotion details also the commerceItems will contain a price info this will give you the adjustments that are applied to each of the commerce item in the order object.